# Как сделать свою форму для добавления записи в post type

Tags: php, wordpress

Я новичок в wordpress да и в php тоже.
я создал свой post type, и теперь хочу сделать свою форму для добавления записи.
создав запись через форму wordpress(которая в админ панеле)в браузере взял все необходимые параметры запроса.
вот моя форма:

```
function myshortcode( $atts ) {
    ?>
<form method='post' action='/wp-admin/post.php'>
<input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="316ec84581" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=post_type_name" />
<input type="hidden" id="user-id" name="user_ID" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenaction" name="action" value="editpost" />
<input type="hidden" id="originalaction" name="originalaction" value="editpost" />
<input type="hidden" id="post_author" name="post_author" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" id="post_type" name="post_type" value="post_type_name" />
<input type="hidden" id="original_post_status" name="original_post_status" value="auto-draft" />
<input type="hidden" id="referredby" name="referredby" value="http://wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?post=105&#038;action=edit" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wp_original_http_referer" value="http://wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?post=105&amp;action=edit" />
<input type='hidden' id='auto_draft' name='auto_draft' value='' />
<input type='hidden' id='post_ID' name='post_ID' value='112' />
<input type="hidden" id="meta-box-order-nonce" name="meta-box-order-nonce" value="d30eea6016" />
<input type="hidden" id="closedpostboxesnonce" name="closedpostboxesnonce" value="969e69d646" />
<input type="hidden" name="samplepermalinknonce" value="fa72ed3972"/>
<input type='hidden'name='' value=''/>
<input type='hidden'name='wp-preview' value=''/>
<input type='hidden'name='original_publish' value='Отправить+на+утверждение'/>
<input type='hidden'name='publish' value='Отправить+на+утверждение'/>   
<input type='hidden'name='tax_input[Model][]' value='0'/>
<input type='hidden'name='post_name' value=''/> 
    <input name='post_title'>Название</input>
    <textarea cols='5' name='content' rows='5'>Описание</textarea>
    <input type='submit' value='Отправить'/>
    </form>
    <?php 
}
add_shortcode('donate', 'myshortcode');
```

когда она отрабатывает, запись не добавляется.

Подскажите, что не так делаю?

Comment: Зачем какая-то своя "форма" для добавления записей?

Comment: @SeVlad в задаче сказано сделать свою форму

Comment: Чтобы ставить такие задачи (и уж тем более реализовывать) нужно понимать ЦЕЛИ. Исполнителю к тому же нужно понимать, что  "форма" - это РЕДАКТОР (TinyMCE по дефолуту) + кучка разных полей. Всем этим можно в ВП управлять. Менять и добавлять в тч. Отсюда вопрос - чем не устраивает дефолтное и что нужно сделать? (только про "формы" не говори, если хочешь сделать правильно и безопасно)

Answer (score 1):

Можешь поставить плагин WP-Recall и он позволяет строить и выводить для разных типов записей свои формы. Поля там гибко настраиваются

Answer (score 0):

https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_post_type вп кама дает возможность добавить coustum post type то что Вам нужен :)
все ответы на Ваш вопрос есть там

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]